# how can I upload fields from dropdown menu into database then retrieve later?

Tags: mysql, database, forms

Im doing a simple store / shopping cart and I want to be able to have the user select the color and size of the item in one simple drop down before they hit BUY. so basically, insert something like this into a row in the table....

```
<select name="product_options">
<option selected>Black - Small</option>
<option selected>Black - Medium</option>
<option selected>Black - Large</option>
<option selected>White - Small</option>
<option selected>White - Medium</option>
<option selected>White - Large</option>
<option selected>White - Extra Large</option>
</select>
```

..then retrieve it later on the product info page as options to the user.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table that contains all of your options above.
2. Use a scripting language such as PHP to call the database, retrieve your options, then output those options into a dropdown list.